# How can I only plot a CONUS map in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I have a dataset that has data for not only CONUS but also the island areas and Alaska. Now, I want to plot only the data for CONUS. I know I can subset it easily. But is there any easier way to that? Maybe an option in ggplot I don't know?

Here is the code:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon( data=usamap, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),colour="black", fill="white" )+
  geom_point(data=df,aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude))+
  scale_colour_gradientn(name = "DL",colours = myPalette(10))+
  xlab('Longitude')+
  ylab('Latitude')+
  coord_map(projection = "mercator")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = c(.93,.20),panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#808080"))+
  ggsave("test.png",width=10, height=8,dpi=300)
```

Here is the dataset:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1z5uquhtc2b9nd/exported.csv?dl=0
```

Comment: Since there is no data in your question, I cannot really help you. But, I would subset data before I would draw a map with ggplot. In this way, I try to make codes easy to read.

Comment: How is "the data for CONUS" defined? Is "CONUS" a geographical region? Oh, is it the "Contiguous US" (ie the USA minus AK and Hawaii)? How can you subset it easily? Show us. Because the easiest thing might be to add a dplyr filter. Do you also need to take AK out of usamap too? Questions questions. Please improve your question with some edits.

Comment: @Spacedman CONUS means continental united states....

Comment: I have attached the data now. @jazzurro

Answer (score 1):

You can do it and also use a decent projection at the same time:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readr) 
library(dplyr)

us <- map_data("state")
us <- fortify(us, region="region")

# for theme_map

devtools::source_gist("33baa3a79c5cfef0f6df")

# read your data and filter out points not in CONUS

read_csv("exported.csv") %>%
  filter(Longitude>=-124.848974 & Longitude<=-66.885444,
         Latitude>=24.396308 & Latitude<=49.384358) -> data

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=us, map=us,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region, group=group),
                    fill="#ffffff", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=data,
                      aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude),
                      color="#cb181d", size=1, alpha=1/10)
gg <- gg + coord_map("albers", lat0=39, lat1=45)
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

You have no aesthetic color mapping I can see, so your color scaling will have no impact. I used an alpha for overlapping/close points instead.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I've added customized legends for multiple colors but used your basic setup.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your reposted question, I think by far the best way is a simple subset. From this [link](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-longitude-and-latitude-of-a-bounding-box-around-the-continental-United-States), you can see the box around the continental USA is:

```
 (-124.848974, 24.396308) - (-66.885444, 49.384358)
```

if you do a simple subset:

```
  usamap<-usamap[usamap$Longitude > -124.848 &
                 usamap$Longitude < -66.886 &
                 usamap$Latitude > 24.3964 &
                 usamap$Latitude < 49.3844, ]
```

You will get your required points.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you'd be interested in a `ggplot2` solution, you might consider modifying the arguments in `coord_map()`.  For example:

```
  coord_map(project = "globular", 
                      xlim = c(-125, -66), 
                      ylim = c(24, 50))
```

Of course, the `"mercator"` argument works, too!